# CC.Net Build Server -- how to find the NUnit test that does not complete at all?

Tags: nunit, cruisecontrol.net

I have a test suite of ~ 1500 tests and they generally run and finish within 'reasonable time'.

Recently, however, I've changed parts of the code to use threads -- and now my builds fail from time to time by simply timing out. I imagine that a thread refuses to die and the build waits until reaching the maximum build time.

My problem is how to detect which test is causing the problem?

Can I activate some logging that shows me that a test has started/finished? I can of course be done by inserting code in every single test method - or just the fixtures, but that is A LOT of work that I'd rather avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest upgrading to NUnit 2.5 and decorating your tests with [Timeout](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=timeout&r=2.5.10) attribute, specifying maximum per-test run time. For example, you can put this in your `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```cs
[assembly: NUnit.Framework.Timeout(100)]
```

NUnit will now launch each test in a separate thread and cancell it if it exceeds its time slot. However, this might be costly, so it's probably better to identify long-running tests and then remove assembly-level attribute in favor of test-fixture time slots. You can also override this on individual tests, assigning them more time to run.

This way you move the timeout/hang detection from CruiseControl.Net to NUnit and get information inside the report on the tasks that did not complete properly. Unfortunately there's no way for CC.Net to get this information when it has to kill the process because of timeout.

Comment: Fantastic; even better than what I hoped for!
Thanks!